# I'm trying to make a clicker game for Python using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm relatively new to Python, and have been using pygame to make a simple idle clicker game. I'm a second year engineering student in high school, so I have a small background in C, but Python is a new territory for me.

I've made it to the point where I have two buttons, one for a multiplier, and one, which is the main button you click. I'm trying to figure out how I can make some kind of upgrade path that allows money to be passively generated over time. (i.e. when the button is pressed the first time, the cost is subtracted, and 1 money is added every second, then 2 when the button is pressed again, then 4, and so on).

I've tried to use some kind of while loop, but that results in the game dramatically slowing down, and the other buttons not responding. I've tried placing this code in different places, and have swapped out while and if multiple times, but that either doesn't work, or it yields the same result, mentioned above. Here is the loop for adding the money. The code below uses import time.

```
  while autocost == 1:
      time.sleep(1)
      money = money + autolvl
```

Here is an example button for the multiplier.

```
class multiplier:
def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
    width = image.get_width()
    height = image.get_height()
    self.image = pg.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), int(height * scale)))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.topleft = (x, y)
    self.clicked = False
def draw(self):
    global money
    global multlvl
    global multcost
    pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
    if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
        if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
            self.clicked = True
            if money >= multcost:
                money = money - multcost
                multcost = multcost * 3
                multlvl = multlvl *2
    if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
        self.clicked = False
    screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
```

Values would be changed based on the needs of the button (in this case, swapping out variables like, autolvl and autocost.

Comment: Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post to focus your question on a much narrower problem

Answer (score 0):

If a loop is very fast, in your case you will get money faster.

Therefore you have to multiply the autolevel with the time that the loop took. If a loop takes 5 seconds, you need to add 5 times the money. If a loop takes 0.001 seconds, you need to add 0.001 times the money.

You added a sleep function that slows down the loops, but doesn't time the loop to exactly 1 second (or 1 millisecond, i am not sure)

```
import time

loop_start = time.time()

while True:
    if autocost == 1:
        money += autolevel * loop dt

    loop_dt = time.time() - loop_start
    loop_start = time.time()
```